# DSpace 4.1: Tomcat doesn't work, taking forever to access DSpace

Tags: tomcat, dspace

I've installed DSpace 4.1, in Ubuntu 14.04, following the [DSpace 4.x Documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Installing+DSpace), using Apache Tomcat as the Servlet engine.

However, when I entered the URL to enter DSpace, it lasts forever to enter. No matter which web app I'm trying to enter, it simply doesn't open anything. Even the web apps provided by Tomcat (docs, examples, manager...) don't open.

The way I deployed the web apps was creating a XML file for each one (plus a ROOT.xml file) in the `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost` directory, as recommendad in the documentation mentioned above.

I've both restarted Tomcat, restarted my computer, but still, it takes forever to (not) open the web apps.

Software Info:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).
- DSpace 4.1, binary release.
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check catalina.out and dspace logs. 
If you see an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`  you need to increase it.
This can be done adding the JVM argument : -XX:MaxPermSize=128m to catalina.sh

Or you can delete unused aplications (lni, sword...)